# Remove element of arraylist from user's input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, while-loop, element

I need to remove an element from an `ArrayList` using user's input. 
Not really asking for a solution, but more of a guide in the right direction.

```
public class BFFHelper 
{
    ArrayList<BestFriends> myBFFs;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public BFFHelper()
    {
        myBFFs = new ArrayList<BestFriends>();
    }

    public void addABFF()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a first name: ");
        String firstName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a last name: ");
        String lastName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a nick name: ");
        String nickName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a phone number: ");
        String cellPhone = keyboard.next();
        BestFriends aBFF = new BestFriends(firstName, lastName, nickName, cellPhone);
        myBFFs.add(aBFF);            
    }

    public void changeABFF()
    {
        System.out.println("I am in changeBFF");
    }

    public void removeABFF()
    {
        //System.out.println("I am in removeABFF");
        System.out.print("Enter friend's name to remove: ");

        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (i<myBFFs.size() && !found)
        {
            if (myBFFs.get(1).getfirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) && (myBFFs.get(1).hetlastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))                   
                i++
        }        
    }

    public void displayABFF()
    {
        System.out.println("My Best Friends Phonebook is: ");
        System.out.println(myBFFs);
    }            
}
```

this is what i have for my main class

```
public class BestFriends {

    private static int friendNumber = 0;
    private int friendIdNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    private String cellPhoneNumber;


    public BestFriends (String aFirstName, String aLastName, String aNickName, String aCellPhone)
    {
        firstName = aFirstName;
        lastName = aLastName;
        nickName = aNickName;
        cellPhoneNumber = aCellPhone;
        friendIdNumber = ++friendNumber;   
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getNickName()
    {
        return nickName;
    }

    public String getCellPhone()
    {
        return cellPhoneNumber;
    }

    public int getFriendId()
    {
        return friendIdNumber;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return friendIdNumber + ". " + firstName + " (" + nickName + ") " +  lastName + "\n" + cellPhoneNumber + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get user input? Or are you stuck on the logic to remove the element?

Comment: Hint on naming: if a class is called BestFriend**s**; I would expect that it somehow deals with "plurals"; like knowing about two people that are best friends. But it looks like your class only knows about a simple person (that has some id). So, there is some misconception here - either your class has the wrong name; or its content doesn't at all reflect its name!

Comment: Hint: override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the `BestFriends`, and you'll be able to remove it using `List::remove`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Remove element of `ArrayList` from user's input?

One way to do such thing is to use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and call [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) when you **find a match**, something like this:

```
// Iterate over the list myBFFs
for (Iterator<BestFriends> it = myBFFs.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    BestFriends bf = it.next();
    if (/*some test here*/) {
        // Found a match to remove
        it.remove();
        // Exit from the loop
        // To be added if and only if you expect only one match otherwise keep iterating
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Assuming that you use Java 8, you can rely on the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for such need.

**In case you want to remove the first match**

```
myBFFs.stream().filter(bf -> /*some test here*/).findFirst().ifPresent(myBFFs::remove);
```

This approach uses [`List#remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) to remove a unique object.

**In case you want to remove all matches**

```
 myBFFs.removeAll(
     myBFFs.stream().filter(bf -> /*some test here*/).collect(Collectors.toList())
 );
```

This approach uses [`List#removeAll(Collection c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) to remove a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Elements can be removed from an ArrayList using in various ways, for example by calling [list.remove(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)); or alternatively, by simply specifying the [object to remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).

Just study the Javadoc for those methods. In addition to that, there are calls like *removeAll()* that remove *all* the arguments provided to the call.

Side note: there is *at least* one bug in your code:

```
if (myBFFs.get(1).getfirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) && (myBFFs.get(1).hetlastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))
```

should probably read.

```
if (myBFFs.get(i).getfirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) && (myBFFs.get(i).hetlastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))
```

Assuming that you are looping with i for a reason; and that you don't want to compare element[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) to itself all the time.

And while we are at it: you could improve your abstractions. Obviously your program is about "humans". Humans normally have fixed names, haven't they. Meaning: have a class that just represents a human being; with **final** fields for information that can't change. Such fields are initialized via the constructor; and you dont have any setters for those.